# Comparing values from different keys in scala / spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to find the difference between values for keys that are related (but not the same). For example, lets say that I have the following map:

```
(“John_1”,[“a”,”b”,”c”])
(“John_2”,[“a”,”b”])
(“John_3”,[”b”,”c”])
(“Mary_5”,[“a”,”d”])
(“John_5”,[“c”,”d”,”e”])
```

I want to compare the contents of Name_# to Name_(#-1) and get the difference. So, for the example above, I would like to get (ex:

```
(“John_1”,[“a”,”b”,”c”]) //Since there is no John_0, all of the contents are new, so I keep them all
(“John_2”,[])  //Since all of the contents of John_2 appear in John_1, the resulting list is empty (for now, I don’t care about what happened to “c”
(“John_3”,[”c”])  //In this case, “c” is a new item (because I don’t care whether it existed prior to John_2). Again, I don’t care what happened to “a”. 
(“Mary_5”,[“a”,”d”]) //There is no Mary_4 so all the items are kept
(“John_5”,[“c”,”d”,”e”]) //There is no John_4 so all the items are kept.
```

I was thinking on doing some kind of aggregateByKey and then just find the difference between the lists, but I do not know how to make the match between the keys that I care about, namely Name_# with Name_(#-1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my issue as follows: 
First create a function that computes the previous key from the current key

```
def getPrevKey(k: String): String = {
  val (n, h) = k.split(“_”)
  val i = h.toInt

  val sb = new StringBuilder
  sb.append(n).append(“_”).append(i-1)

  return sb.toString 
}
```

Then, create a copy of my RDD with the shifted key:

```
val copyRdd = myRdd.map(row => {
  val k1 = row._1
  val v1 = row._2

  val k2 = getPrevHour(k1)
  (k2,v1)
})
```

And finally, I union both RDDs and reduce by key by taking the difference between the lists:

```
val result = myRdd.union(copyRdd)
  .reduceByKey(_.diff(_))
```

This gets me the exact result I need, but has the problem that it requires a lot of memory due to the union. The final result is not that large, but the partial results really weigh down the process.

Answer (score 0):

Split "id":

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq(
  ("John_1", Seq("a","b","c")), ("John_2", Seq("a","b")),
  ("John_3", Seq("b","c")), ("Mary_5", Seq("a","d")),
  ("John_5", Seq("c","d","e"))
).toDF("key", "values").withColumn(
  "user", split($"key", "_")(0)
).withColumn("id", split($"key", "_")(1).cast("long"))
```

Add window:

```
val w = org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
  .partitionBy($"user").orderBy($"id")
```

and `udf`

```
val diff = udf((x: Seq[String], y: Seq[String]) => y.diff(x)
```

and compute:

```
 df
   .withColumn("is_previous", coalesce($"id" - lag($"id", 1).over(w) === 1, lit(false)))
   .withColumn("diff", when($"is_previous", diff( lag($"values", 1).over(w), $"values")).otherwise($"values"))
   .show

// +------+---------+----+---+-----------+---------+                               
// |   key|   values|user| id|is_previous|     diff|
// +------+---------+----+---+-----------+---------+
// |Mary_5|   [a, d]|Mary|  5|      false|   [a, d]|
// |John_1|[a, b, c]|John|  1|      false|[a, b, c]|
// |John_2|   [a, b]|John|  2|       true|       []|
// |John_3|   [b, c]|John|  3|       true|      [c]|
// |John_5|[c, d, e]|John|  5|      false|[c, d, e]|
// +------+---------+----+---+-----------+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should have added that my data is an RDD that is almost 2TB large. Given that that is the case, I think I cannot use coalesce, or it would kill the parallelism, right?
Also, RDD doesn't seem to have a .toDF method, is it another equivalent one I could use?

Comment: This is SQL coalesce not `RDD.coalesce` or `DataFrame.coalesce`. Window functions shuffle, but you cannot do much about it I think.